# Accessing ASP.Net Membership in a Console Application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, console-application

I'm writing a simple utility console app to add new users, etc, to an SQL Server Membership Store.

The issue I'm running into is that I can't seem to add a reference to System.Web, so I can't access the Membership stuff.  How does one go about doing this?

NOTE: I've found a few questions on stackoverflow that seem similar, but the answers revolved around MVC, and after attempting the suggested answers, the problem still remains.

Edit:
Oded helped lead me to the answer.  By default it was filtering by the "client profile", which doesn't have System.Web available.  I had to retarget to .Net 4 instead of .Net 4 client profile as described in the following MSDN article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Why can't you add a reference to `System.Web`? What errors are you getting?

Comment: What version of the framework are you targeting (look at the project properties)? If it's the client profile, change it.

Comment: It's targetting .Net 4.0.  And I'm not getting any errors, the dll is just _not in the list_

Comment: Oded, I just double checked, and it does state it's filtering by the client profile, so that makes sense.  Any advice on how to change that?  first time I've ever ran into that issue (I'll google in the meantime).

Comment: I have never seen this, so don't have an answer for you. No idea where the references list is configured.

Comment: I found it.  If you want to create an actual answer with this information, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are targeting the full framework in your project (right click on the project node and select `Properties`) - In the `Application` tab there is a drop down for `Target Framework`.

Make sure this does not use a client profile.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly prevents to you to add reference to System.Web in a console application? Just add appropriate reference via references management in VS. After that you should configure your application with App.config and work with Membership services as in web applcation

Comment: In the "Add Reference" dialog, I have access to the "System.Web.ApplicationServices" and the "System.Web.Services" dll, but no "System.Web" dll.  See edit.