# How to access the ProfileCommon and aspMembership in a Console application?

Tags: asp.net, console-application

I got confused while accessing the aspMembership and Profiles in Console application.

I had did this in the createuser event in Web application.

Here the code is:

```
ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(CreateUserWizard.UserName, true);
            p.Country = ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Country")).SelectedValue;
            p.Gender = ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Gender")).SelectedValue;
            p.Age = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)CreateUserWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Age")).Text);
            p.Save();

 Membership.CreateUser(CreateUserWizard.UserName, CreateUserWizard.Password, CreateUserWizard.Email, CreateUserWizard.Question, CreateUserWizard.Answer, true, out memberStatus);
```

Now what I need is, I need to do these functionalities in Console application also.

I can't access the ProfileCommon and MembershipUser class, since I have added the Profile and it's properties in App.config in the console application.

Comment: Membership class is member of System.web namespace but in console application it is not accessible. you need to add namespace of that class. but I doubt that this will work for console app.

Comment: @RajeshKumar in the following link http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/.NET_Framework_2.0/Q_23337502.html they have used Membership class,except Profile..

Comment: I have spent hours for doing this..till now searching but didn't find the solution..I think that it is possible in console application

Comment: See this link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398194/accessing-asp-net-membership-in-a-console-application